# How to add a radius to a container when animated- Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want the pages to view in full screen without the radius, but as I open my dashboard, I want the Container to have a radius.

Comment: Do you think you can improve your question with some code you have already tried?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: isFullScreen ? null : BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
  child: ...
),

...
```

Comment: It would be even better to change Container to AnimatedContainer to get a more interesting and dynamic effect.